# Превращение одного тега в другой

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>HJ3</title>
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>
    <p>press Ctrl+E for edit text</p>
    <p>press Ctrl+S for save text</p>
    <hr>
    <span id = "t1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Quo debitis illum dolore ratione dignissimos exercitationem iste 
    rerum quia laudantium placeat ex voluptate eius, dolorem possimus 
    eaque sit tempore commodi sunt. </span>
    <p id = 'p2'> </p>
</body>
<script> 
      document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 69) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
            }
        }, false)
      document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 83) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
            }
        }, false)

    document.body.onkeydown = (e) => {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 69) {
    let el1 = document.getElementById('t1');
    let el2 = document.createElement('textarea');
    el2.innerHTML = el1.innerHTML;
    el1.parentNode.replaceChild(el2, el1); }
    if  (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 83) {
    let el1 = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    let el2 = document.createElement('span');
    el2.innerHTML = el1.innerHTML;
    el1.parentNode.replaceChild(el2, el1); } //Ошибку выдает в этой строке 
}
</script>
</html>
```

Ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceparent'

Сама программа отлично работает до момента использование клавиш "ctrl + S", если же использовать эту комбинацию сразу то мне любезно удалит текст.

Comment: что такое `e.keyCode === 69`? что такое `e.keyCode === 83`? `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')` - возвращает коллекцию, а ты ее как элемент пытаешься использовать

Comment: ну в ошибке же написано, что не возможно прочитать свойство, el2 undefined

Comment: @Grundy Прошу: https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode/for/alt

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолмак, `el2` не может быть `undefined` :) потому что оно в обоих случаях из `createElement` получается.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолмак  Как мне исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолмак А, так я просто обращаюсь к Tagname и оно его не находит?

Comment: @Davq, какая связь у `alt` и кодов 69 и 83? Обрати также внимание, что `keyCode` свойство - deprecated

Comment: @Grundy немного не так написал, значение его undefined.

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, учту что свойство устарело. Сайт что я вам кинул указывает keyCode буквы, я подумал что это удобно поэтому и использовал

Comment: @Davq, магические числа - это всегда неудобно. Или ты каждый раз будешь ходить на сторонний сайт, чтобы вспомнить обработчик какой клавиши ты хочешь поправить.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолмак, не стало понятнее :) проблема не в el2

Comment: @Grundy Не планирую. Спасибо, я учту, но проблема сейчас не в числах)

Comment: @Davq, да, не в числах, проблема указана в первом комментарии.

Comment: @Grundy действительно это так ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для textarea используйте `value`, а вы используете `el1.innerHTML`.
И `getElementsByTagName` заменил на `querySelector`

Вот рабочий код:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 69) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false)
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 83) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false)

document.body.onkeydown = (e) => {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 69) {
    let el1 = document.getElementById('t1');
    let el2 = document.createElement('textarea');
    el2.value = el1.innerHTML;
    el1.parentNode.replaceChild(el2, el1);
  }
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 83) {

    let el1 = document.querySelector('textarea');
    let el2 = document.createElement('span');

    el2.innerHTML = el1.value;


    el1.parentNode.replaceChild(el2, el1);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>press Ctrl+E for edit text</p>
<p>press Ctrl+S for save text</p>
<hr>
<span id="t1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Quo debitis illum dolore ratione dignissimos exercitationem iste 
    rerum quia laudantium placeat ex voluptate eius, dolorem possimus 
    eaque sit tempore commodi sunt. </span>
<p id='p2'> </p>
```

P.S:: Ваш вариант сейчас не предусматривает, если сперва нажмут `Ctrl+S`, если будете использовать учтите это.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, обращайтесь!